# How do you change an iPad back from Korean to English?

Tags: ipad, ios, language

How do you change back an iPad from Korean to English?

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a link](http://www.trickyways.com/2010/04/how-to-change-ipad-language/) that shows step by step with images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No. That desn't work to change the basic Apple iPad instructions on an iPad bought fom Korea. Why does Apple make it so difficult? I guess it's yet another high profit money-spinner by Apple that forces us to go to an expensive Apple store and pay lots of money to a so-called "genius" salesman. Sigh.
Looks like there's no way to change the ASIC Apple instructions - not the international language. That's a childishly simple and so obvious change, despite the inferences of the unnecessary illustrations here.